# Selecting rows dynamically based on the size of the Dataframe

Tags: pandas, xlsxwriter

I am trying to apply a conditional format to a range of cells based on the size of the Dataframe:

```
percent_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.00%'})

range_1 = ## This should have the range of rows starting cell 'C23' to the number of rows in the dataframe
```

I plan to get the get the size of the Dataframe using `df.shape[0]` and I trying to add this count to the value in `range_1`.

So if `df.shape[0]` = 30 then `range_1 = "C23:C53"`. <- Because formatting should start from C23 and then format the next 30 rows. The count of 30 is obtained from the size of the Dataframe.

```
worksheet.conditional_format(range_1, {'type': 'no_blanks', 'format': percent_fmt})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
row_count = 30
range_1= f'C23:C{23+row_count}'
range_1
'C23:C53'
```

Is this what you are asking for?